# .Net Core - What are the things to know to learn Hello World

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I've read some questions here, but typically it's not an answer for me.

So, here's my question:
Since I'm a Beginner,

> 1. Do I have to install Web Server using .Net Core?
> 2. What is the name of the Web Server I'll used or install? IIS or Personal Web Server?
> 3. Does this run on Visual Studio 2013 Desktop Edition? or What IDE to use?
> 4. Do they have a SDK of .Net Core 1.0.3?(I've seen during net surfing)

I'm really sorry, I mix mind and doubt what to do.

> What are the IDE or Software I need to use to enable to see my "Hello
>   World" running from .Net Core 1.0.3?

Please understand I'm a beginner,
thank you

Comment: easiest way to install VS 20015 or 2017 and use Core project template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge:

*1.Do I have to install Web Server using .NET Core?*

You need a web server to be able to run a web app. You can use [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel), which is self hosted and can be installed from Nuget. Low friction.

*2.What is the name of the Web Server I'll used or install? IIS or Personal Web Server?*

`Kestrel` is all you need. There are other options of course.

*3.Does this run on Visual Studio 2013 Desktop Edition? or What IDE to use?*

I don't know if you can run VS 2013.
You can use [Visual Studio Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/), and [Visual Studio 2015 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) will also work.

*4.Do they have a SDK of .NET Core 1.0.3?(I've seen during net surfing)*

Everything is done using `Nuget`.

*5.What are the IDE or Software I need to use to enable to see my "Hello World" running from .Net Core 1.0.3?*

For a "Hello World" app you just need Visual Studio Code. You can find plenty of tutorials on the web.

[This one is from Microsoft and uses VS 2015.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc)

[And this one is .NET Core with VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/dotnet)

[And also this one (VS Code).](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dotnet/Get-started-with-VS-Code-using-CSharp-and-NET-Core)

You can find plenty more. [Follow this link for the official MS .NET Core.](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)

And if you want to keep yourself up to date with `.NET` and some other stuff I really like this site [The Morning Brew.](http://blog.cwa.me.uk/).